# /bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied

Tags: docker

При попытке запуска 
     docker run -t -i mongo:3.4 /bin/bash

Сразу после запуска контейнера
Выводится текст в логах
/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied

Comment: в инструкции ж написано, как запускать: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo#how-to-use-this-image

Comment: так и запускаю как там написано

Comment: найдите, пожалуйста, десять отличий: 1. `$ docker run -d mongo:3.4` 2. `$ docker run -t -i mongo:3.4 /bin/bash`

Comment: Теперь получилось